# Multiple MySQL operations on table interaction

Tags: mysql, triggers, sql-update

What is the best way to proceed in the following scenario

I have my first_table which holds Datas and a second one which is related to this on ID (ID = id=related) and there are no foreign keys involved

```
first_table
----------------------------------------------
ID   | Datum      | Type          |Status
----------------------------------------------
123  | 2013-09-11 |   relational  |   1
----------------------------------------------
1234 | 2013-09-11 |   relational  |   1
----------------------------------------------
185  | 2013-09-11 |   normal      |   1
----------------------------------------------
```

In my second_table there is an status update on interaction which means I set 0 as value.

And here comes the thing where I have problems to step forward, because I try to solve this issue on mysql side not involving server side scripts

If `SELECT * FROM second_table WHERE id_related = '1234' AND status = 1` is empty I want to update my first tables status setting it's value 0

```
UPDATE first_table SET status = 0 WHERE ID = 1234

second_table
---------------------------------------------
ID | id_related   | some_column_value | status
---------------------------------------------
1  | 123          | some_column_value | 1
---------------------------------------------
2  | 123          | some_column_value | 0
---------------------------------------------
3  | 1234         | some_column_value | 0
---------------------------------------------
4  | 1234         | some_column_value | 0
---------------------------------------------
```

Is there a way to do all this with MySQL setting up a trigger?

Comment: What if the first table does not have a record with that specific `ID` value? Do you want to perform an `INSERT`?

Comment: if in first table there is no record than the second table record won't exist

Comment: And what if the record in second table exists? Do you still want to update first table?

Comment: no than in this case there is no update in first table I have a colummn in first which defines if there are values related to this id on the second table if Type relational than there are items

Comment: Ok. You can go with [*answer by Stropharius*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22957565/767881) below, except with the `ELSE ... UPDATE` part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to keep the status values up-to-date during INSERTs you can create trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `tr1` AFTER INSERT ON `second_table`
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM second_table WHERE status = 1 AND id_related = NEW.id_related ) THEN
        UPDATE first_table SET status = 0 WHERE ID = NEW.id_related;
    ELSE
        UPDATE first_table SET status = 1 WHERE ID = NEW.id_related;
    END IF;
END;
```

This will keep 1 for status in first_table while there are related rows in second_table having 1 as status and 0 otherwise.
If you need to perform the same operation for UPDATEs of the second_table, you need to create the 'AFTER UPDATE' trigger with the same body as well.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback I was just giving a try with your query but there is no status update in my first table when all matched records status on second table set  0

Comment: It is not enough to trace all the changes of second table. This will work for updates only when the existing records are already consistent. If you insert the records, you should also control the status values, for example, create the same 'AFTER INSERT' trigger.